# Check if a class is equal to a template instance or a normal class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have an `integral_constant` to determine if a class is in a provided list of classes:

```
template <typename T> using decay_t = typename std::decay<T>::type;

template <typename... Args> struct SOneOf : std::integral_constant<bool, false>
{
};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Tail> struct SOneOf<T1, T2, Tail...>
    : std::integral_constant<bool, SOneOf<T1, T2>::value || SOneOf<T1, Tail...>::value>
{
};

template <typename T1, typename T2> struct SOneOf<T1, T2>
    : std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<decay_t<T1>, decay_t<T2>>::value>
{
};

template <typename T> struct SOneOf<T> : std::integral_constant<bool, false>
{
};
```

I also know that I can give templated classes as template arguments via `template <template <typename> class T>`.

Assuming I have two classes

```
template <typename T> class CClassA;
template <typename T> class CClassB;
```

and am in a function `template <typename TF> function f()`.

How can I generically check if `TF` (e.g. `int` or `CClassA<double>`) is a `CClassA` or a `CClassB` or a `float`?

I'd like to achieve something like

```
SOneOf<TF, CClassA, CClassB, float>::value
```

Comment: Neither `CClassA` nor `CClassB` are classes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're trying to get that information inside the function template you can use partial specialization:

```
template <bool...> struct bool_pack;
template <bool... B>
using any_true = std::integral_constant<bool,
  !std::is_same<bool_pack<false, B...>, bool_pack<B..., false>>{}>;

namespace detail {
  template <template <class...> class, typename>
  struct IsSpec : std::false_type {};
  template <template <class...> class T, typename... U>
  struct IsSpec<T, T<U...>> : std::true_type {};
}

template <typename U, template <class...> class... T>
using IsSpecialization = any_true<detail::IsSpec<T, std::decay_t<U>>{}...>;
```

Usage would be simple:

```
static_assert( IsSpecialization<CClassB<int>, CClassA, CClassB>{}, "" );
static_assert( !IsSpecialization<void, CClassA, CClassB>{}, "" );
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a2e292c139d6418). The extra comparison for `float` has to be done separately, e.g. via `std:is_same`.

If you need different code based on the template the type is a specialization of, use overloading.

```
template <typename Arg>
void f( CClassA<Arg> const& obj ) { /* … */ }
template <typename Arg>
void f( CClassB<Arg> const& obj ) { /* … */ }
```

Comment: The question is more on how to mix complete and incomplete type in a query. As shown in the question : `SOneOf<TF, CClassA, CClassB, float>::value`. So you do not answer.

Comment: @galop1n That is nonsense and cannot be made flexible anyway  (I assume you meant templates by "incomplete types"? Those are two different things in the context of C++). I provided a way to check that with multiple templates though, and the additional check can then be performed separately.

Comment: @galop1n Well.. the first version helped me out, although it wasn't generic, while the second version answers my question, but didn't help me out (as the answer is, that it's not possible). So I assume both (Columbos original answer and your answer) are right :)

Comment: @Uroc327 Well, you can just write `IsSpecialization<TF, CClassA, CClassB>{} || std::is_same<TF, float>{}` as the boolean expression, and even put that into an own template. That's what I meant.